# Any logical meaning behind (1-p value)*coefficient?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, least-squares, conditional-probability, interpretation

Say I have regressions of 3 groups, A, B, and C. I regress some outcome variable Y on an independent variable X.

$Y_A = \alpha_A + \beta_A*X_A$

$Y_B = \alpha_B + \beta_B*X_B$

$Y_C = \alpha_C + \beta_C*X_C$

Say the result is that $\beta_A$ looks huge from the first regression, but the p value is large.
On the regression for group B, $\beta_B$ is smaller, but the p value is small.

**To compare the groups, would it ever be appropriate to use $\beta*(1 - \text{p value})$?**

I could also do a multiple regression with a dummy and interaction term for groups:

$Y = \alpha + \gamma*group + \beta*X + \delta*X*group$

To compare, would it ever be appropriate to get the individual coefficients from the group terms and multiply by 1 - p value?

The context of this is that I want to be able to say something about both the magnitude and probability of the coefficient, or penalize the coefficient for a high p value. If p value is treated as a probability, then one minus it should be the probability that my coefficient is accurate, right?

Alternatively, it doesn't have to be 1-p value, I could do $\text{coefficient}*\text{(1-pvalue)}^2$ for a different type of penalty.

Is there literature surrounding this, or am I completely misunderstanding p values? Such as, does the interpretation of the p value as a probability break down if my errors are non-normal?

Thank you very much!

========EDIT 1:========

I realize that maybe the application of my question is not very clear. Say I wanted to *rank* students A, B, and C (group) based on their test performance (Y) across a year. Each student has a certain median income (X). I get regression coefficients from these equations, each with varying p values, $\alpha$, and $\beta$. Naively ranking students based on their $\alpha$ would be incorrect, because I would not be looking at the probability that the alpha was different from 0 (null). So, my question is, in this application, would it be appropriate (or completely flawed) to multiply (1-p)*coefficient or ((1-p)^n)*coefficient to rank my students?

Comment: A p-value *is* a probability. However, it is a very specific probability. Be careful when interpreting the p-value.

Comment: It is possible that there is a shrinkage argument to be made here.  You need to find a Bayesian prior that justifies it; otherwise, I would discard the idea out of hand.

Comment: @BigBendRegion, how do you mean? as in a logical reason why the parameter would needed to be shrunk?

Comment: I've edited my post to show the reason I'm considering shrinking the parameters.

Comment: See James-Stein estimates.  Also ridge regression. BLUPs.  Bayes in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To compare, would it ever be appropriate to get the individual coefficients from the group terms and multiply by 1 - p value?"

I don't think so. Note particularly that the coefficient has a specific meaning giving you the estimated average amount by which $Y$ increases when increasing $X$ by one unit (everything else fixed if anything else is in the model). This would be destroyed by your proposal.

"The context of this is that I want to be able to say something about both the magnitude and probability of the coefficient"

Which is nicely done by using *both* the coefficient value and the p-value, rather than aggregating them into one value.

"If p value is treated as a probability, then one minus it should be the probability that my coefficient is accurate, right?"

No. The p-value is the probability that given that the true coefficient is zero, an estimated coefficient as large as the one you estimate on your data or even larger (in absolute value) would be observed in random data, which is quite different from your interpretation.

"Alternatively, it doesn't have to be 1-p value, I could do coefficient∗(1-pvalue)^2 for a different type of penalty."

This doesn't solve any of the problems of your first proposal.

"...because I would not be looking at the probability that the alpha was different from 0 (null)"

This is not the correct meaning of the p-value either.

Regarding the example task of ranking student groups (?), note also that the p-value will depend on the sample size, so involving the p-value would penalise students in smaller groups as p-values are easily smaller for larger sample sizes.
If I understand your aim right, I'd just use the estimated coefficients. The p-value gives an indication of the uncertainty (however a confidence interval would be better for this, and probably a bit easier to interpret), but regardless of the p-value the estimated coefficient is the best guess you have from the data of what the coefficient actually is. That the uncertainty for different coefficients is different is good to know, but I don't see why this should affect the ranking of students in different groups differently. Note that confidence intervals will also show you that in case a coefficient is larger but also has a larger p-value, not only is it more easily possible that indeed it would have been zero or close to zero, it is also more easily possible that it could have been *even larger*. The overall uncertainty is just bigger, in *both* directions.

Comment: This was so clear, thank you!